# Create views by joining 3 tables in MySQL server

Tags: mysql

I'm creating MySQL views by join of 3 tables, orders,products,purchases [(database link)](https://github.com/phpcontrols/inventory-manager/blob/master/db/InventoryManager_2017-06-22.sql) by below code.

```sql
CREATE VIEW full_inventory_details
AS
     SELECT orders.*,
         products.ProductName,
         products.PartNumber,
         products.ProductLabel,
         products.StartingInventory,
         products.InventoryReceived,
         products.InventoryShipped,
         products.InventoryOnHand,
         products.MinimumRequired,
         purchases.id
     FROM(
     ( orders 
     INNER JOIN products 
     ON orders.ProductId=products.id)
     INNER JOIN purchases 
     ON orders.ProductId=purchases.ProductId);
```

Everything looks good, still not getting anything updated. I'm not getting new views. Kindly looking for help. Thanks.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL - please correct your tags.

Comment: Also you should never `SELECT *` in a view.

Comment: And what does this "still not getting anything updated." actually mean? Are you trying to update via your view?

Comment: I'm not getting new views `full_inventory_details`  in mysql workbench